# HashMap through WebSocket in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, hashmap

I have an hashmap (const HashMap = require('hashmap');) in a nodejs application that I'm sending to my client through a websocket like this :
io.sockets.emit('state', myHashmap);

but when I am not able to loop through the values in the client side. I'm not able to build a hashmap with the json data that I get from the websocket.

Can someone help me to read the json data of my hashmap and create a new one on the client side ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I see now that you are using a hashmap module. You are either know what you are doing, and using it for a good reason, or maybe you came from Java and then you just better be using JS Objects, which are extremely fast and optimized. You can also use native Maps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

---

The rest is about objects, but with plain objects you probably can just send them throw web sockets, without stringifing (most likely socket library will be stringifying them on server and parsing them on client internally).

---

You might try to stringify it in node.js and parse on the client.
Like so

`io.sockets.emit('state', JSON.stringify(myHashmap));`

and then on the client parse it

`const data = JSON.parse(payload)`

I guess you are talking about js objects like `const myHashmap = {};` ?